# Laravel blade conditionals doesn't work in components when the condition is given by component method

Tags: php, laravel-7

I have created a Laravel blade component. Inside of it I have a method called "something" that needs to evaluate some logic.

Then in the component view, I display some information based on the condition.

If the condition returns true, the information is displayed. But when it is false, nothing happens.

**app/View/Components/ExampleComponent.php**

```php
<?php

namespace App\View\Components;

use Illuminate\View\Component;

class ExampleComponent extends Component
{
/**
     * Create a new component instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
       //
    }

    public function something(){
       if (2 + 2 === 4) return true;  // some logic
       else return false;
    }

    /**
     * Get the view / contents that represent the component.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\View\View|string
     */
    public function render()
    {
        return view('components.example-component');
    }
}
```

**resources/views/components/example-component.blade.php**

```php
<div>
  @if(something)
     <h1>
       2 + 2 = 4
     </h1>
  @else
     <h1>
       That is witchery <!-- This doesn't show if I evaluate 2 + 3 === 4 -->
     </h1>
  @endif
</div>
```

Comment: Hi! You should change `@if(something)` to `@if(something())` to call the function.

Answer (score 1):

you should use `something` like these:

```
<div>
  @if($something())
     <h1>
       2 + 2 = 4
     </h1>
  @else
     <h1>
       That is witchery <!-- This doesn't show if I evaluate 2 + 3 === 4 -->
     </h1>
  @endif
</div>
```